# scope=publish_stream not working

Tags: facebook, permissions

I added publish_stream to the list of permissions I want when people install my Facebook app, but now it's not working.

It works perfectly for my test application on localhost, but I have the exact same permissions scope on my live app, and it won't work. For existing users it doesn't ask for any new permission and for new users it only asks for email.

I've even added other permissions like user_photos to the string and that works fine for new and existing users, but publish_stream does NOT get asked for.

Has something changed?

Comment: For new users, the will get the new auth-dialog that has a two step process. In the second step, they are asked for the extended permission of publish_stream. I set this up in the application settings. However, I need this permission for existing users, how can I prompt existing users for this permission. The Scope parameter doesn't NOT work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send users who have not granted the extended permission of publish_stream back through the auth-dialog process.  The first step will be skipped automatically if they have accepted the app previously.